# Pass custom Header for download image in SDWebImage iOS sdk

Tags: ios, image, sdwebimage

I need to pass custom HTTPHeader for fetch image but getting error 401. Same token is working for other api.

Header is passed in sdwebimage requesturl:

[image: image of debug point]

I am passing custom headers like below code.

```
SDWebImageDownloader *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader;
[manager setValue:[DefaultsValues getStringValueFromUserDefaults_ForKey:kTokenKey] forHTTPHeaderField:@"authToken"];
[manager setValue:[DefaultsValues getStringValueFromUserDefaults_ForKey:kUserEmail] forHTTPHeaderField:@"email"];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL STRING"] options:SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize, NSURL * _Nullable targetURL) {

    NSLog(@"%tu",receivedSize);

} completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL finished) {
    if (error == nil) {
        cell.profileImage.image = image;
    }
}];
```

Comment: your setting Header is correct or not? are you sure you have to set two header like key and email? might be you need only token. Ask you backend which key and how what header you need to set?

Comment: @NitinGohel : Yes i need to pass two headers. Same is working in Postman

Comment: your code seems right! make sure that your token and email is correct and your server is not down!

Comment: did you get any error ? can you try to NSLog error.localize?

Comment: got error like : "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=401 "(null)""